# Having issues with updating state of deeply nested arrays in Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I've got a state in redux that looks like this:

[image: state]

I'm trying to update the flags of "false" of selected arrays, but have trouble grasping such deeply nested array modification in redux.

Here was my take, that gives me syntax errors:

```
case 'SET_FLAG':{
    return {
        ...state,
        pickedSquares: [
            ...state.pickedSquares,
            pickedSquares[action.index]: [
                ...state.pickedSquares[action.index],

            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

And I probably still need to go 2 levels deeper.

I would appreciate the help.

Comment: Is `pickedSquares` an array? And does the order of its elements matter (like if it were changed after updating the state, would that be alright)?

Comment: Yes, it's an array. And order does matter and it cant be changed, since it basically contains keys for rendering dynamic content

Answer (score 2):

I recommend making a copy of `pickedSquares` and then modifying the copy directly. Since `pickedSquares` is an array, and not a JS object, you won't be able to spread and overwrite values in the manner you are currently trying.

Here is an example of a way to solve the problem based on the code you have provided:

```
case 'SET_FLAG':
    const pickedSquaresCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state.pickedSquares)); //make a deep copy
    pickedSquaresCopy[action.index] = action.newValue;
    return {
        ...state,
        pickedSquares: pickedSquaresCopy
    }
```

What is shown is only a modification one level deep, but you can make them arbitrarily deep by navigating the array/object levels and modifying values that need to be modified.

Comment: I'm getting some weird endless loops when trying this, but maybe it's tied to the other piece of code. Before it loops it seems to be updated the way I want, so I'll test it more and update accordingly, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best way but works:

```
case "SET_FLAG": {
  const newArr = state[action.payload].map(el => {
    if (el === false) {
      return true;
    }
    return el;
  });

  const newState = state.map((el, index) => {
    if (index === action.payload) {
      return newArr;
    }
    return el;
  });

  return newState;
}
```

I don't know how performant this will be. Maybe you can try to make a deep copy as @Henry Wood suggested and find a way doing nested changes. But with my method, you are not mutating the state directly without doing a deep copy, too.

If you like the ternary operator:

```
case "SET_FLAG": {
  const newArr = state[action.payload].map(el =>
    el === false ? true : el
  );

  const newState = state.map((el, index) =>
    index === action.payload ? newArr : el
  );

  return newState;
}
```